# Timage gets white and bitmap has size 0 bytes

Tags: delphi, bitmap

I have some  data stored inside my TImage Component. I want to save the image as an bitmap. Executing this code the TImage content gets white and only a bmp file with 0 bytes has been created on the harddisk. What is wrong with my code ?

```
  MainStatusbar.SimpleText := 'save the image .... ';
  if SaveDialog.Execute then
  begin
    Image1.picture.Bitmap.SaveToFile(SaveDialog.filename);
  end;
  MainStatusbar.SimpleText := 'done ';
```

Comment: Your image is either empty, or its picture is not a bitmap. Use `Image1.Picture.SaveToFile(SaveDialog.FileName)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

`TPicture` is a container for multiple different types of images. If the current image is not a `TBitmap`, then `Picture.Bitmap` will not contain your image. When you refer to `Picture.Bitmap` your original image will be destroyed, and an empty `TBitmap` created. So, the obvious explanation in that `Picture.Bitmap` is empty when `SaveToFile()` is called.

You should be saving your image by calling `SaveToFile` on the `Picture` object instead:

```
Image1.Picture.SaveToFile(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the original image is not a bitmap then calling `Picture.Bitmap` will erase the content and create an empty bitmap. Depending on the original picture format an automatic conversion (e.g. from an icon) may be possible, but has to be done outside of TImage.

Answer (score 2):

If the `TImage.Picture.Graphic` property does not currently hold a `TBitmap` then accessing the `TImage.Picture.Bitmap` property will free the current `Graphic` and replace it with a blank `TBitmap`.  This is documented behavior.

Since you want to save a bitmap, check if the current `Graphic` is already a `TBitmap`.  If so, save it as-is.  Otherwise create a temp `TBitmap`, assign the current `Graphic` to it, and then save it.

```
MainStatusbar.SimpleText := 'save the image .... ';
if SaveDialog.Execute then
begin
  if Image1.Picture.Graphic is TBitmap then
    Image1.Picture.Bitmap.SaveToFile(SaveDialog.FileName)
  else
  begin
    Tmp := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      Tmp.Assign(Image1.Picture.Graphic);
      Tmp.SaveToFile(SaveDialog.FileName);
    finally
      Tmp.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
MainStatusbar.SimpleText := 'done ';
```